# Negative Binomial Regression: is parameter theta (R) the reciprocal of parameter kappa (SAS)?

Tags: r, sas, negative-binomial-distribution

After some frantic googling I do believe the answer is yes, but more so I am frustrated that the relation between the two parameters seems to be nowhere described explicitely so I do it here. (I hope this isn't against the rules of stackexchange.)

[This very nice article](http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1141&context=usdeptcommercepub&sei-redir=1&referer=http%3A%2F%2Fscholar.google.nl%2Fscholar_url%3Fhl%3Dnl%26q%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fdigitalcommons.unl.edu%2Fcgi%2Fviewcontent.cgi%253Farticle%253D1141%2526context%253Dusdeptcommercepub%26sa%3DX%26scisig%3DAAGBfm3vz9gDbxRveIafikl02v0aeUyu0w%26oi%3Dscholarr%26ei%3DDj9VUqWlL6LG0QXe1oHwAg%26ved%3D0CDAQgAMoADAA#search=%22http%3A%2F%2Fdigitalcommons.unl.edu%2Fcgi%2Fviewcontent.cgi%3Farticle%3D1141%26context%3Dusdeptcommercepub%22) states: we will denote the random variable Y having a negative binomial distribution as Y ~ NB($\mu, \kappa$) with a parameterization such that E(Y) = $\mu$, var(Y) = $\mu + \kappa \mu^2$.

I take this latter equation as the definition of $\kappa$.

[Apparently](http://books.google.nl/books?id=Ohks0xwvyT4C&pg=PA196&lpg=PA196&dq=kappa+parameter+negative+binomial+proc+glimmix&source=bl&ots=PYKpaGQ8VN&sig=5sNEB-7H7ZocErTKhi35ORKd2lA&hl=nl&sa=X&ei=lEBVUqCnNcTJ0QXppYGoAg&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=kappa%20parameter%20negative%20binomial%20proc%20glimmix&f=false) this kappa is implemented in SAS.

Now turning to R, the function `glm.nb` in the `MASS` package contains a parameter $\mu$ which is obviously the same $\mu$ as above and a parameter $\theta$. The question is how $\theta$ and $\kappa$ are related. The documentation for `glm.nb` only refers to it as an "additional parameter". The answers to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10419/what-is-theta-in-a-negative-binomial-regression-fitted-with-r) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10457/interpreting-negative-binomial-regression-output-in-r?rq=1) stackexchange questions directly imply that $\theta = 1/\kappa$, but [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30360/what-is-the-distribution-of-theta-in-a-negative-binomial-model-glm-nb-with-r?rq=1) question [EDIT: since removed] seems to suggest that $\theta = \kappa$.

The [help page for negative binomial in R](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/NegBinomial.html) is nice and introduces a parameter called `size` that equals $1/\kappa$. Fitting `glm.nb` on random data generated by `rnbinom` for various choices of $\mu$ and `size` seems to support the thesis that $\theta = 1/\kappa$ (i.e. that $\theta$ = `size`) but also that for large values of size the estimation is poor.

Summarizing: I do believe that $\theta = 1/\kappa$ but it would be nice if there were an easily googlable place on the internet stating this explicitly. Maybe one of the answers to this questions can serve as such a place?

Comment: since you are right with your suspicion, why not answer your question yourself? I means you basically state the answer in the question anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the suggestion of @Momo I will answer the question myself. What I had forgotten yesterday when I posted this question, is that I can just see what `glm.nb` does by typing "glm.nb" into the console. From the code it returns it can be inferred that indeed the variance equals $\mu + \mu^2/\theta$ so that $\theta = 1/\kappa$.

Also I'd like to use the opportunity to advertise this [article](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v27/i08/paper) I found since then, also addressing these matters.